# Creating Custom hotkey for 'show_wire'

Tags: shortcut

I'm trying to make hotkey for this option:

[image]

Like that:

[image]

But this isn't working.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you just want to toggle Wireframe View on the selected Object, you need a different context for the hotkey.

Since what you want to influence is a *Checkbox* that would be `wm.context_toggle`

In the *Context Attributes Field* that will appear when you set this, just paste the Data Path that you copied from the Checkbox, in our case `object.show_wire`

This should look something like that:
[image: Setting a Custom Hotkey for Show Wire on Active Object]

Comment: For Blender 2.93+ this would be `object.show_wire` in the Context Attributes field. But does anyone know how to get this shortcut working on MULTIPLE objects, not just the last selected object? Corresponding question on [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/t/shortcut-for-viewport-display-wireframe-but-on-multiple-selected-objects/1311849)

Comment: Usually, the wireframe overlay is used for multiple objects, however, if you don't want it to show on ALL, but only a subselection: select the objects, then either hold the Alt key before checking the "wireframe" box, or check it (like regular), then right click it and select "copy to selected".